# Upgrade JBoss Remoting とは

Tags: java, jboss

JBoss Remoting の Upgrade について仕組みの概要だけでもご存知の方、ご教示頂けますでしょうか。

具体的には既存のクライアントーサーバシステムをリバースエンジニアリングしていて、当該処理を行なっていた為、何をしているのか知りたいしだいです。

おそらく、処理フローとしては

1. クライアントアプリがサーバへログイン（HTTP）
2. その後、Upgrade JBoss Remoting（具体的にはHttpUpgrade.performUpgradeメソッドを使っています）

なのですが、上記2でUpgradeFailedException というものが発生してしまいます。

要因としては、今までなかったクライアント・サーバ間にプロキシを噛ませています。プロキシはHTTPのみ転送しています。

JBoss Remoting とはなんなのかなど、部分的にでもご教示頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

UpgradeFailedException のcause byを含んだスタックトレースを示したほうがよいのではないでしょうか。

また、JBoss Remotingについてはちょっとググると、こんなのが見つかります。
https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1003/24/news099_2.html